# How to get the total size of hard disk of Windows machine?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, operating-system, wmi

I'm trying to get the total size of hard disk of a Windows machine.

One of the approaches which I used is using WMI query but it seems that WMI doesn't return correct size above 2TB, I have verified the result in WMI Tester. It doesn't result correct size of the hard disk. I have verified the results in 1TB machine and 2.5 TB machine and I'm sure about WMI returning incorrect value above 2TB.

I have also tried to check the hotfixes for WMI in the MS site but they have not released any hotfix related to this issue.

Any suggestion for any other approach to get the total size of hard disk. I need to implement the approach in VC++ project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937.aspx), which has an `lpTotalNumberOfBytes` output parameter. It is subject to per-user disk quotas, though.  If you need the raw byte size of the physical disk, use [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) to open a handle to the desired disk and then use [`DeviceIoControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216.aspx), specifying the [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365178.aspx) control code, to get the disk's total byte size.